# Align td element at top with dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

In this [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xJCTcdd5g3a5EPasYdzd?p=preview) I've made a table resembling a calendar, my problem is that the days within the table does not always start from the topleft corner even though I've added the following css

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I don't understand why this doens't work as it has worked previously in other scenarios. Does it have to do with the element `font` I'm appending?

Comment: I suggest you use an editor that spots these errors like `Visual Studio Code`

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah the chrome console never picks up on these things, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a **comma** in `word-wrap:break-word`

```
td {
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    word-wrap:break-word /* HERE  */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Solve that and it works!

Comment: Oh, thank you! since it was only a typo, should I remove my question?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is, that u're missing a ; on the line before in your code.

Like this, it works like charm:

```
td {
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot ';' end of line 'word-wrap:break-word'

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a semicolon at the location specified below. putting semicolon will solve your problem.

```
td {
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 2px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    ****word-wrap:break-word (missing ; )****
    vertical-align: top;
}
```